# MySQL LEFT JOIN optimisation

Tags: mysql

I have the following query where

- A has 1 000 000 rows
- B, C, D has 150 000 rows each
- E has 50 000 rows

The query itself seems to take around 50 seconds to complete. It will usually contain a WHERE clause as it is doing a search through all the possible data in the database. Is there any way this could be improved?

```
SELECT A.one, A.two, A.three
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON ( A.id = B.id ) 
LEFT JOIN C ON ( A.id = C.d ) 
LEFT JOIN D ON ( A.id = D.id ) 
LEFT JOIN E ON ( A.name =  E.name 
AND  E.date <= A.date ) 
ORDER BY A.id ASC
```

Explain query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY  | 17      | NULL      | 357752 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 17      | db.A.id   |      1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | C     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 17      | db.A.id   |      1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | D     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 17      | db.A.id   |      1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | E     | ref    | Name,Date     | Name     | 62      | db.A.name |      1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: What WHERE clause does it usually contain? And -- how many rows do you expect each of B, C, D, and E to have *for each row of A*?

Comment: Can you attempt to join only table A and E and see how long it takes? Maybe the string matching is making things slow.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend replacing the indexes that you have on `E` - `Name` and `Date` with a dual-column index on both, because for that last join, you're effectively selecting from `E` where `name` and `date` match a criteria.  Because `name` is eq, it should be first in the index.

```
ALTER TABLE `E` ADD INDEX idx_join_optimise (`name`,`date`)
```

This will let the join select fully use an index.

Also - I assume that this is an example query, but you don't seem to be using `B`, `C` or `D` which is possibly slowing it down.

If the `WHERE` clause that you mentioned uses values from the other tables, I'd suggest changing them to an `INNER JOIN` based on the criteria.. (It'd help if you posted some example of what you were doing)